# Duplicate column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a table with 4 columns.

```
Id  Description Barcode     Type
1   A01         L001        Loc
2   A02         L002        Loc
3   B01         L003        Loc
4   Root        L004        Parent
5   Emplacement L005        Parent
6   C01         L006        Loc
7   C02         L007        Loc
```

I want to make an UPDATE of the 'Barcode' column with the value in the 'Description' column where the Type column contains "Loc".

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Barcode=Description
WHERE Type='Loc'
```

It seems like I'm getting something wrong.

Comment: You do it right way. Why do you think you're wrong?

Comment: Because I am getting an SQL error

Comment: The problem seems to come from the fact that my WHERE returns more than one values and it dont know wich one to apply

Comment: I haven't figured out what exactly was wrong, but I succeded with a big where with all the ID they were to change. Finding them using a sort. (WHERE (Id=1 OR Id=2 OR...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote `Loc` since it is a string

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Barcode=Description
WHERE Type='Loc'
```

Comment: My bad, i forgot to quote the Loc in the post, but it is in my sql.

Comment: Maybe your `Type` contains whitespaces. Try `where trim(Type) = 'Loc'`

Comment: I just tryed it with my values to make sure and it works, thanks